# Dart: how to override a generic method?

Tags: dart, generic-list

Consider my following base class:

```
abstract class IChat<Message extends IMessage> {

  String get getId;
  
  List<T> getUsers<T extends IUser>();

}
```

Now my extended Model looks like this:

```
class Chat extends IChat<ChatMessage> {
  String id;
  List<ChatUser> members;

  Chat({this.chat, this.members});


  @override
  String get getId => id;

  @override
  List<T> getUsers<T extends IUser>() => members;
  
}
```

`List<T> getUsers<T extends IUser>() => members;` throws an error because I return `List<ChatUser>` instead of `List<T>`. How do I override the method to make this work?  My `ChatUser` class obviously also extends `IUser`.

**Edit**

@jamesdlin gave one solution: `@override List<T> getUsers<T extends IUser>() => members.cast<T>()`. It is possible without type casting?

Comment: You should be able to just use your type in the generic function ie: `List<ChatUser> getUsers<ChatUser>() => members;`

Comment: @Mattia thnx for your reply. Sadly this throws an error aswell: `'Chat.getUsers' ('List<ChatUser> Function<ChatUser>()') isn't a valid override of 'IChat.getUsers' ('List<T> Function<T extends IUser>()').`

Comment: I dont know if there's a better way offhand, but `@override List<T> getUsers<T extends IUser>() => members.cast<T>();` works.

Comment: @jamesdlin nice thank you. But isn't there a way without type casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider what you actually *want* your classes to do.

It seems like the subclass has a specific type of `IUser` that it always wants to return, but a generic function takes its type argument *per invocation*. So, the type should probably be a property of the class, not of the invocation.

Consider:

```dart
abstract class IChat<Message extends IMessage> {

  String get getId;
  
  List<IUser> getUsers();
}

class Chat extends IChat<ChatMessage> {
  String id;
  List<ChatUser> members;

  Chat({this.chat, this.members});

  @override
  String get getId => id;

  @override
  List<ChatUser> getUsers() => members;
}
```

Would that satisfy your needs?

As stylistic comments, your code is very C#-like, and doesn't look like Dart. I'd probably declare the classes as:

```dart
abstract class Chat<M extends Message> {
  String get id;
  List<User> get users;
}

class SomeChat extends Chat<ChatMessage> {
  @override
  final String id;
  @override
  List<ChatUser> users;
  // ...
  SomeChat({this.id, List<CharUser> members, ...}) : users = members;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant and exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! And also thank you for your style commenting, I didn't even know this was a possibility. I started Dart 2 months ago, so I have a lot to learn!